# CyberpowerPC won't start

Tags: boot

I bought this [CyberpowerPC](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883229362) from NewEgg in November 2012.

I haven't done anything to it, so it's exactly as described.  Everything had been working fine until I tried to upgrade the video card to a Zotac Geforce GTX 650 Ti, now I get this message when I startup my pc, "select boot device" or something like that, and the only option is "1. CD/DVD blah blah. " So I choose that one and then I get another screen that says "no bootable device found. Press any key to go back"

Even when I put the gt 610 back on (which is the video card that the computer came with), it gives me the same black screen asking for boot device stuff. What happened?

Why won't my computer boot up to Windows?  What happened to it?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you bumped a SATA data cable while you were in.  Check the hard drive cable.  If that is plugged in properly I would boot off a CD and do a diskcheck.

Comment: That is probably it. But check both the data and the power cable.